# how to find json key value where json array name has space in karate

Tags: karate

I need to assert an array element in a json where array name has space in it

**example json:**

```
{
"integration": {
    "message": {
        "code": 0,
        "description": "Success"
    },
    "serviceData": {
        "TenantID": "1909627861",
        "Company Name": "anupamaCompany",
        "Sub Domain": "testadd",
        "Usage Data": [{
            "Stage": "Test",
            "Service Type": "OrchestrationIntegration",
            "Integration Name": "Add",
            "Applications List": [],
            "createdBy": "Anupama2",
            "Created Date": "2018-10-03",
            "Last ModifiedBy": "Anupama2",
            "Last Modified Date": "2019-01-10",
            "Integration Type": "Light"

        }, {
            "Stage": "Development",
            "Service Type": "OrchestrationIntegration",
            "Integration Name": "Xzxzx",
            "Applications List": [],
            "createdBy": "Anupama2",
            "Created Date": "2019-01-11",
            "Last ModifiedBy": "Anupama2",
            "Last Modified Date": "2019-01-11",
            "Integration Type": "Light"
        }]
    }
}
}
```

value to be asserted:

```
integration.serviceData.["Usage Data"].Stage
```

When I traverse to 'Usage Data' getting an error since it is having space.

Comment: Hi Peter,  That feature is not there for now in our product. If similar case comes in future  I will test that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to access key with space is correct, but it looks you forget to notice the data in "Usage Data", it is an array/list type data.

so you have to access it by index or json deep scan or many other options.

here are few,

```
# to get all usage data as list
* def usageData = $example.integration.serviceData.['Usage Data']
# to get all stage in usage data
* def stages = $example.integration.serviceData.['Usage Data']..Stage
```

Comment: Very quick and accurate reply

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: actually there is a bug that was introduced in 0.9.0 https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/652 - workaround by @BabuSekaran is correct for now

Comment: oops! looks like the issue only with match `* def Stages = $example.integration.serviceData.['Usage Data'][0].Stage` is still intact. great catch @PeterThomas